# Use Apply function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote a function `analysis` that takes a path as input, performs some analysis on the file pointed by the path and returns the result of this analysis.

I have a pandas dataframe containing two columns (labels and paths), and I would like to create a new column with the value (or ideally the values) resulted from the function `analysis(path)` for each of the paths present in the dataframe.

If I correctly understood, it should be possible to use the `apply` function, but I don't have understood how. All the examples I found use lambda functions, and not a 'standard' function.

Could someone provide an example?

Comment: Please provide a sample of code to help us assist you.

Comment: `df['analysis'] = df['path'].apply(analysis)`